# Extract child objects from json object

Tags: json, node.js, xml

I am struggling to convert xml to json object and then extracting nodes from the converted object. I am using busyboy to read from the file uploaded on the server. And after that I am using inspect to convert xml to json and then printing the json object. The final output seems as

```
{ declaration: { attributes: { version: '1.0', encoding: 'utf-8' } },
  root: 
   { name: 'order',
     attributes: 
      { orderid: '123456',
        xmlns: 'http://www.someRandomNameSpace.com' },
     children: 
      [ { name: 'orderperson',
          attributes: {},
          children: [],
          content: 'str1234' },
        { name: 'shipto',
          attributes: {},
          children: 
           [ { name: 'name',
               attributes: {},
               children: [],
               content: 'Adnan Ali' },
```

I want to read the 'name'='Adnan Ali' from this object how will that be done in nodejs ? I mean how can i reach to the object which has name='name' and content='Adnan Ali'.

The print command is
`console.log(inspect(order, {colors: true, depth: Infinity}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search the arrays of objects for the objects you are interested in. There are various ways to do that, including [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (not sure if it is available in all Node.js versions) and [lodash `_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find).

Using `Array.prototype.filter` a solution could look like this (not tested):

```
function findObject(array, key, value) {
    var filtered = array.filter(obj => (obj[key] === value));
    if (filtered.length !== 1) throw new Error('Found ' + filtered.length + ' objects with `' + key + '`=`' + value + '`, expected to find 1.');
    return filtered[0];
}

var shipto = findObject(input.root.children, 'name', 'shipto');
var name = findObject(shipto.children, 'name', 'name').content;

console.log(name);
```

Comment: this is what i was interested in

Comment: causes a build error. Because it is missing a + sign between filtered.length and 'objects with ...' fixed it and it worked. Thanks

Comment: That was the "not tested" part of the answer. ;) I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using NodeJS perhaps giving JSONPath a try would be a good idea. Then you can do something like this:

```
var jp = require("JSONPath");
var tobj = { "declaration": { "attributes": { "version": '1.0', "encoding": 'utf-8' } },
  "root": 
   { "name": 'order',
     "attributes": 
      { "orderid": '123456',
        "xmlns": 'http://www.someRandomNameSpace.com' },
     "children": 
      [ { "name": 'orderperson',
          "attributes": {},
          "children": [],
          "content": 'str1234' },
        { "name": 'shipto',
          "attributes": {},
          "children": 
           [ { "name": 'name',
               "attributes": {},
               "children": [],
               "content": 'Adnan Ali' 
               }
           ]
        }
    ]
}};
var result = jp.eval(tobj, "$..children[?(@.name === 'name' && @.content === 'Adnan Ali')]");
console.log(result);
```

Example output:

```
[ { name: 'name',
    attributes: {},
    children: [],
    content: 'Adnan Ali' } ]
```

(Don't forget to install JSONPath ;-))

Sources:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONPath
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reach the object with `content: 'Adnan Ali'` with this path `data.root.children[1].children[0]`:

```js
const data = {
  declaration: {
    attributes: {
      version: '1.0',
      encoding: 'utf-8'
    }
  },
  root: {
    name: 'order',
    attributes: {
      orderid: '123456',
      xmlns: 'http://www.someRandomNameSpace.com'
    },
    children: [{
      name: 'orderperson',
      attributes: {},
      children: [],
      content: 'str1234'
    }, {
      name: 'shipto',
      attributes: {},
      children: [{
        name: 'name',
        attributes: {},
        children: [],
        content: 'Adnan Ali'
      }]
    }]
  }
};

console.log(data.root.children[1].children[0])
```

Explanation:

`data` is an object that contains a `root` object. `root` is an object that contains a `children` array. The second element in `root.children` (index `1`) is an object that contains another `children` array that contains the object you're looking for at the first index (`0`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's very powerful once you wrap your head around it.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (input) => objectScan(['**'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'value',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value.content === 'Adnan Ali' && value.name === 'name'
})(input);

const tobj = { declaration: { attributes: { version: '1.0', encoding: 'utf-8' } }, root: { name: 'order', attributes: { orderid: '123456', xmlns: 'http://www.someRandomNameSpace.com' }, children: [{ name: 'orderperson', attributes: {}, children: [], content: 'str1234' }, { name: 'shipto', attributes: {}, children: [{ name: 'name', attributes: {}, children: [], content: 'Adnan Ali' }] }] } };

console.log(find(tobj));
// => { name: 'name', attributes: {}, children: [], content: 'Adnan Ali' }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)